# Writefile() fails to write data depending on length of data

Tags: c++, winapi

I have created a function to write raw data to a USB drive: `write(int size,wchar_t data[])`. `data` is the data to be written and `size` is the length of the data.

```
bool write(int size, wchar_t data[])
{
    HANDLE hDevice = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;  // handle to the drive to be written
    

    hDevice = CreateFile(
        GetUSBdrivePath('e'),  // GetUsbdrivePath(char) returns the file path
        (GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE),                // access mode to the drive
        FILE_SHARE_WRITE,               //Shared or exclusive
        NULL,             // default security attributes
        OPEN_EXISTING,    // disposition
        0,                // file attributes
        NULL);
    if (hDevice == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) // cannot open the drive
    {
        cout << GetLastError();
        
        return (FALSE);
    }
    wchar_t *keybuffer = data;
//Sets the start position of the pointer from where it has to write
    if (SetFilePointer(
                        hDevice,
                        ((2)*512),
                        NULL,
                        FILE_BEGIN)
        == INVALID_SET_FILE_POINTER)
    {       
        CloseHandle(hDevice);
        return false;
    }
    

    DWORD NumberOfBytesRead = 0;
    DWORD dwSize = static_cast<DWORD>(size);
    bool flag = WriteFile(hDevice, keybuffer, dwSize, &NumberOfBytesRead, (LPOVERLAPPED)NULL);
    
    CloseHandle(hDevice);
    return flag;
}
```

This function works properly when the size of the data written is 512 or its multiple. But `WriteFile()` fails to write when size is not a multiple of 512. I have read Microsoft's documentation but cannot find anything useful. Why does this happen?

Comment: *You should assume that all Microsoft file systems open volume handles as noncached. The restrictions on noncached I/O for files also apply to volumes.* as result buffer size and write offset must be sector aligned. address of buffer also must be aligned

Comment: @RbMm Can you help me. How do I write so that my data gets written. I was testing for data of large length (16,384)‬ which is a multiple of 512 but it is still not writing. For smaller length it works if multiple of 512

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write whole sectors at a time. That means writing to an offset that is an even multiple of the drive's sector size, and writing blocks of data to that offset which are multiples of the sector size.

If your `data` is not an even multiple of a complete sector, you still have to write a whole sector.  Calculate the starting offset where the desired sector begins, round up your `size` value to the next sector boundary after where your `data` ends, allocate a memory block of that total size from starting offset to ending boundary, copy your `data` into that block where needed, and then write that entire block to the drive.

If you want to write fewer bytes than a complete sector, and you don't want to overwrite existing data before/after your `data` bytes, then you have to read the existing sector(s) first into your allocated memory block, then copy over your `data` bytes into that block as needed, then write the whole block back to the drive.

Comment: :O I had always assumed this was abstracted away by the filesystem and/or drive itself! The _application_ really has to handle this?

Comment: @MooingDuck Normal file I/O handles this for you, yes.  But direct drive access does not, no.